# ::after, ::before selector in element style

Tags: css

I'm doing something like this however, the word `world` won't appear. having that rule declare in the head css, it works fine.

can anyone explain this to me?

```
<span id="aa" style="#aa::after{content=" world";}">hello</span>
```

Comment: There's no selector in inline style - all rules in inline style applies to that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XTdZ6/1/)**

You must separate your CSS from your HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
    <style>
        #aa:after {
            content: 'world';
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="aa">hello</span>
</body>
</html>
```

---

It's also better to create a file with `.css` extension, for example `styles.css`,
and put the style in it:

```
#aa:after {
    content: 'world';
}
```

And in your HTML, link to this file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <span id="aa">hello</span>
</body>
</html>
```

- Be sure that your `html` and `css` file are in the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

No. The style attribute only defines style properties for a given HTML element. Pseudo-classes are a member of the family of selectors, which don't occur in the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` attribute doesn't accept selectors. It only accepts the rules to apply to the current element. You can't do this with a `style` attribute.

Comment: Hello Blender. Thanks for the clarification. Is there workaround for this?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran: Put it in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The `style` attribute applies styles *to the current element*; it cannot contain complete style sheet rules with selectors.

Although the selector in this case happens to match the same element, if it were possible, you would also be able to do this, which would make very little sense:

```
<div id="one" style="#two { display: none; }"></div>
... much content ...
<div id="two">Huh?</div>
```